# Это кот Шовник(,) или, по-другому, именно тот единственный кот, имеющий у нас шов

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Это кот Шовник(,) или, по-другому, именно тот единственный кот, имеющий у нас шов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что да.
Это случай , где союз «или» присоединяет пояснительную конструкцию (обычно обозначающую одно и то же понятие другими словами).

Пример: Бабушка показала мне деревянный ларь, или ящик, широкий вверху и узкий внизу.